Eigenvalues of a matrix $C$,whose elements are $n\times n$ real matrices.
Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ real matrices and let $$C=\begin{bmatrix}
A&B&\\ 
B&A
\end{bmatrix}.$$Which of the following statements are true?

$(1).$ If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A+B$ then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $C$.$(2).$ If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A-B$ then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $C$.$(3).$ If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of either of $A$ or $B$ then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $C$.($4$).All eigenvalues of $C$ are real.


For option(1):Let $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A+B$ then there exists a vector $v\ne 0$ in $\Bbb R^n$ s.t. $(A\pm B)v=\lambda v$.Now define $u=\begin{bmatrix}
v&\\
\pm v
\end{bmatrix}$.Then $C(u)=\begin{bmatrix}
A&B&\\ 
B&A
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
v&\\
\pm v
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
Av\pm Bv&\\
\pm Av+Bv
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda v&\\
\pm\lambda v
\end{bmatrix}=\lambda u.$
Therefore $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $C$.Hence options (1) and (2) are correct.Option(4) need not be correct as $A+B$ can have complex eigenvalues.I am unable to solve option(3).I tried above argument but unable to find an eigenvector of $C$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$.I think option(3) is incorrect but unable to find a counter.

Option (3) is false. Consider $A=B^T=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ for instance. Here $C$ does not share any eigenvalue with $A$ and $B$ because it is nonsingular but $A$ and $B$ are nilpotent.
